# write callback called multiple times

Tags: gulp, task, gulp-task

When I run my gulp task I am getting an error, which is as follows:

> Potentially unhandled rejection [2] Error: write callback called multiple times

It is probably related with this line of code, due to it working with this excluded.

```js
.pipe($.autoprefixer({browser:['last 2 version','> 5%']}))
```

```js
gulp.task('styles',function (done){
  //return 
  gulp.src(config.less)
  .pipe($.less())
  // .pipe($.autoprefixer({browser:['last 2 version','> 5%']}))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(config.temp));
  done();
});
```

Any help is most appreciated!